# Prioritize Wrapping in CSS

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have a document  that look like (simplified):

```
<div style=" display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; ">
  <div>stuff</div>
  <div>
    Lots<br>
    of<br>
    vertical<br>
    content<br>
    <span>And one long sentence of text</spend>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes the screen is wide enough to display everything with no wrapping at all.  When it's not, I want the sentence in the span to be wrapped, which has the smallest effect on the total layout.  Instead, both firefox and chrome are wrapping the outermost div.

Is there any way to specify that this block of text should be the first thing to wrap?  That it should make do with less width rather than shoving other things out of its way?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, where you add `flex: 1` to the `span`'s parent

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/dnf9xuvz/)

```html
<div style=" display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; ">
  <div>stuff stuff stuff</div>
  <div style="flex: 1">
    Lots<br>
    of<br>
    vertical<br>
    content<br>
    <span>And one long sentence of text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for the simplified version that I posted, but not the real thing.  Something to do with additional nesting of dom elements, I guess.

Comment: @dspeyer If you post the real thing, I might be able to solve that one too, for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

What seems to work is setting

```
max-width: 0px
```

for the span.  I would expect this to make it always break after every word, but instead it does what I want.

On Firefox and Chrome, anyway.  I half expect it to break on some other browser.